# JQuery Accordion without JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an accordion using JQuery without using JQuery UI but the accordion does not work.

HTML

```
        <div id="accordion">
        <button class="accordionButton">Button</button>
            <div class="accordionContent">
              <p>Text</p>
            </div>

        <button class="accordionButton">Button</button>
            <div class="accordionContent">
              <p>Text</p>
            </div>
```

JQuery

```
    $('#accordion').find('.accordionButton').click(function(){

         $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

         $(".accordionContent").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
```

The page loads correctly with the content of the accordion hidden but selecting any of the accordionButtons does not display the information.

Comment: Well, looks like jQuery UI is required for accordion to work, no? Not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple slide function on click:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#accordion .accordionButton').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).closest('.content').find('.accordionContent');
    $('#accordion .accordionContent').not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
#accordion .content .accordionContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="content">
    <button class="accordionButton">Button</button>
    <div class="accordionContent">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <button class="accordionButton">Button</button>
    <div class="accordionContent">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```